# How many bytes occupied by a member in Redis Set

Tags: c++, memory, nosql, redis, hashset

I am using Redis as a in-memory hashset. After I insert 1M 8-byte keys (in binary) into a Set, I find Redis USED_MEMORY comes to about 100M, which means a single member takes 100 bytes? why ?

Or how can I conf Redis to save it memory usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should always detail your setup for this kind of question, since the memory layout is dependant on the OS, memory allocator, platform and Redis version.

On a 64 bits Linux box with Redis 2.4, a 1M items set of 8 bytes keys eats 87 MB.

It seems a lot compared to the size of the keys, but any dynamic data structure supporting efficient accesses to its items involve an overhead. The smaller your items, the larger the overhead.

With Redis, large sets are implemented using separate chaining hash tables. Each entry is represented by the following structure:

```
typedef struct dictEntry {
    void *key;
    void *val;
    struct dictEntry *next;
} dictEntry;
```

Because there is no 24 bytes class supported by the memory allocator (jemalloc), 32 bytes are used. In this structure, val is set to NULL (this is a set), and key points to an object defined as follows:

```
typedef struct redisObject {
    unsigned type:4;
    unsigned storage:2;     /* REDIS_VM_MEMORY or REDIS_VM_SWAPPING */
    unsigned encoding:4;
    unsigned lru:22;        /* lru time (relative to server.lruclock) */
    int refcount;
    void *ptr;
} robj;
```

This structure takes only 16 bytes. It points to the key data itself, represented by this variable-length structure:

```
struct sdshdr {
    int len;
    int free;
   char buf[];
};
```

The keys are on 8 bytes, plus a nul char, so the size will be 17 bytes per keys. The next allocation class is 32 bytes with jemalloc, so this structure will take 32 bytes.

All in all, each items will cost: 32+16+32 = 80 bytes. There are 1M ot them. Add some space for the hash table itself (containing at least 1M pointers to dictEntry struct), and you get a result which is very close to the 87 MB we can measure on this platform.

Optimizing the memory footprint of a large set is not really trivial. Redis performs optimization when the sets are small (by default less than 512 items) and the keys are actually integers. See more information [here](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).

One possible optimization is to increase the set-max-intset-entries parameter, and split the set in various pieces. For instance item keys can be hashed to distribute the items on various sets. Instead of just myset, you have myset:0, myset:1, myset:2 ... myset:n. To check a given item is is the set, a hash value is calculated on the key to find the correct myset:X entry, and then this specific entry is checked. Purpose is to keep the size of all those sets below the set-max-intset-entries parameter to benefit from the memory optimization. Of course, it makes all operations done on the set more complex, so it is really a tradeoff between complexity and memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the underlying structure of each member of the set, it's impossible to say. However, if you are storing key/values, then each member is storing the key and the value (even if the value is empty, it still needs to hold a reference for it).

For fast finds on keys, the underlying structure is most probably a tree, which means it needs to store a left and a right (or red/black) pointer to the left and right descending nodes in the tree for each member. In a 64bit system, those pointers are 8 bytes each.

To efficiently allocate and deallocate key/value pairs, the each member node may have data members that indicate it's size and it's availability (allocated, deleted), so that each member node can be allocated from a pool of memory and either garbage collected or marked as deleted and reused. Typical pool allocation doubles the pool size each time the previous pool is filled to minimize the heap contention, which is very important for performance in multithreaded applications. Your 100M of memory usage may contain 50M of unused (but allocated) key holders.

Why do you want to save memory usage? Are you planning to store billions of hash keys?

Comment: This is quite wrong. Sets in Redis are stored as hash tables, not trees. Redis does not pool allocations: it mainly relies on the excellent jemalloc general purpose allocator (starting version 2.4). There is no garbage collection in Redis: reference counting is used instead.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. In my defence, I was only guessing as to the internal structure that Redis uses, and I found your detailed answer above interesting and illuminating.